# 11g get invalid invalid rowid through v$logminer_content

Tags: oracle, oracle-cdc

I used logminer to get change data from archivelog, but get invalid rowid 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'. How could this happened. It just a insert operation.

- copy catalog

  `begin
     sys.dbms_logmnr_d.build(options => dbms_logmnr_d.STORE_IN_REDO_LOGS);
  end;
  /`
- add logfile

  `begin
    sys.dbms_logmnr.add_logfile(LogFileName => '/arch/archlog/SZO1ABS9/ARC0000286133_0846017616.0001',
                                Options     => sys.dbms_logmnr.NEW);
  end;
  /`
- start logmnr

  `begin
    sys.dbms_logmnr.start_logmnr(Options => sys.dbms_logmnr.DICT_FROM_REDO_LOGS +
                                            sys.dbms_logmnr.COMMITTED_DATA_ONLY);
  end;
  /`
- fetch result

  `select scn,start_scn,commit_scn,timestamp,operation,row_id,sql_redo,sql_undo from v$logmnr_contents
  where row_id = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' and scn = '7590067871061';`

[image]

Comment: Is this a programming question?  If so, can you share any code?

Comment: please see my updates

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you got around this by now lol, but recently had to deal with the same problem.

I'm not sure what the underlying cause but I worked out two approaches to fix it.

1. In a postprocessing pass, I fixed up these rowid's by issuing a new query to get the table's pkey value via MINE_VALUE, you can then use that to query the table via its pkey for the rowid.
2. If you have flashback enabled, this fixup is apparently already taken care of.  If you look at the same transaction in FLASHBACK_TRANSACTION_QUERY or a versions query on the table, you'll see the correct ROWID and no 'AAAA..'